# Is there any way to copy textfiled data with it's textstyle format in flutter

Tags: flutter, copy, clipboard, paste, textstyle

Is there any way to copy text-filed with different font format in flutter
when i paste my copy text-filed data form my flutter to any app it shows 
in a plain text it not show that font what i set in flutter app 
what i do to copy text-filed data with it's font format

Answer (score 0):

You can't as `TextField` and `TextArea` in other applications as in your have predefined text styles which were explicitly set for the field or implicitly by the application's `theme`. This styling mechanism can be confirmed for Flutter `TextField` according to its [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/style.html).